# Is there a function $f$ satisfying this integrability condition?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I am wondering if it is possible to find a real valued function $f$ such that
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2 T(f(x))} \ dx < \infty
$$
where $T(x)=\cos(x)$ or $T(x)=\sin(x)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Letting $f(x)=arccos(\frac{1}{x^2})$ if $T(x)=cos(x)$ seemingly works.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike, but you're function is not real valued :)

Comment: Why do you have $<\infty $ above? Do you mean for $T(f(x))$ to be nonnegative? Or are you asking if the integral can converge as an improper Riemann integral (which allows for oscillation from plus to minus)?

Comment: Yes I am indeed asking if the integral can converge as an improper Riemann integral.

Comment: OK, then you should take the $<\infty$ out of there, and rephrase as such.

Comment: Please don't change your question substantially after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible for any $f(x)$ which is everywhere positive, because to compensate for the $\frac1{x^2}$ behavior near $x=0$, $T(f(x))$ would have to go to infinity as $x\to 0$.  But neither sine nor cosine can grow greater than $1$.

So we must consider an oscillatory $f(x)$ and now we need to deal with an integral that involves an infinite number of "pole" singularities, growing denser and denser as $x\to 0$.  The first promising candidate is
$$
f(x) = \sin\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)
$$
so that we want to study 
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^{-2}}{\sin\left[\sin\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)\right]}dx
$$

This integral works out to an infinite sum of pole contributions plus a sum of contributions between the poles. It appears to be finite, but I have not done enough to prove it is.

However, Mathematica implies that this is still an infinite integral, or rather, one that cannot be done numerically.

Comment: Very interesting answer, thank you Mark, I'll think about this !